# flutter, android studio, auto import, dart

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, auto-import

Is there a way to make Android Studio auto import packages from external libraries?
What I mean by that is I got to pub.dev getting package I want and then in Android Studio I can write name of the class I want to use from that package and IDE would auto import it for me... I believe in VS Code is as simple as on mac cmd + . (fullstop) is driving me nuts

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can add any external package from [pub.dev](https://pub.dev) using this command in terminal:
`flutter pub add package-name`